# Please tell me how to solve lwip tcp server error

Tags: tcp, stm32

I made this Source code to implement `lwip` tcp server

If you try to remove the st-link wire and do it without debugging, the server itself doesn't work.

I try to find a way, but I don't know where the problem is.
If the LED on the board blinks, it means it's down.
Is there a problem with why the server is not working?

If you turn it to debugging, you receive it without any problems, generate a message, and then send it.

Then isn't there a problem with the Source code?

If the connection itself is not working when there is no debugging, I don't think the server is created

But if it's a circuit problem, I think it's weird to be a server when you debug it
I don't know where to look.

When debugging, the client sent and received properly when it connected to the client from hercules or Raspberry Pi

```
void Tcp_Task(void const * argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Tcp_Task */
  
  struct netconn *conn, *newconn;
  err_t err, accept_err;
  struct netbuf *buf;
  void *data;
  u16_t len;
  
  MX_LWIP_Init();
  
  LWIP_UNUSED_ARG(argument);
  
  conn = netconn_new(NETCONN_TCP);
  
  if (conn!=NULL)
  {  
    // netconn_bind(conn, NULL, port 번호)
    err = netconn_bind(conn, NULL, 5001);
    
    if (err == ERR_OK)
    {
      netconn_listen(conn);
      
      while (1) 
      {
        accept_err = netconn_accept(conn, &newconn);
    
        if (accept_err == ERR_OK) 
        {
          while (netconn_recv(newconn, &buf) == ERR_OK) 
          {
            do 
            {
              netbuf_data(buf, &data, &len);
              memcpy(receivemsg, data, len);
              
              
              transmitmsg = procPacket();
              
              msg_len = getsendPackSize();
              
              netconn_write(newconn, transmitmsg, msg_len, NETCONN_COPY);
              
            } 
            while (netbuf_next(buf) >= 0);
            
            netbuf_delete(buf);
          }
          netconn_close(newconn);
          netconn_delete(newconn);
        }
       
       osDelay(100);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      netconn_delete(newconn);
    }

  }

  
  /* Infinite loop */
    for(;;)
    {
      osDelay(100);
    }
  /* USER CODE END Tcp_Task */
}
```

lwip tcp server Source code site
[[https://blog.naver.com/eziya76/221867311729]](https://blog.naver.com/eziya76/221867311729)(lwip tcp server)

I don't think I can implement the server if I turn the board off and on or without debugging, but I don't know where to find the problem
Please let me know if the Source code is the problem, and if the other place is the problem, please tell me how to find it

---

I'm writing this using a translator, so please understand

Comment: "Sauce" is an odd choice of word here. Do you mean "source code"?

Comment: I modified it And it's the source code